Load Phi 3 small on Nvidia Tesla V100 - Flash Attention
I would like to inquire about the possibility of uploading and fine tuning a Phi 3 8k small. When I load the model, I get an error about missing Flash attention. If I want to install the given package, I get this error :
RuntimeError: FlashAttention is only supported on CUDA 11.6 and above.  Note: make sure nvcc has a supported version by running nvcc -V.


      torch.__version__  = 2.3.1+cu121

But I have the required version of pytorch and CUDA (torch 2.3.1 and cuda 12.1)
Is it because I am using a Tesla V100 graphics card? Is there any way to load the model also with this graphics card?
I found this in the documentation for the Phi 3 mini on Huggingface:

If you want to run the model on:
NVIDIA V100 or earlier generation GPUs: call AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained() with attn_implementation="eager"

Does this also apply to the Phi3 Small 8k?? Beacause when I try to load it, the error occurs
model = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained("path", num_labels=num_labels ,attn_implementation="eager" )

AssertionError: Flash Attention is not available, but is needed for dense attention

Or should I try the ONNX version or it is just for inference?
Thank you.


There is no way to use flash-attention on architectures <= V100, nor is it planned to be implemented soon.
You can have a look on this github thread:
https://github.com/Dao-AILab/flash-attention/issues/148
It also provides explanation for the lack of future integration:

The tensor cores (for matmul) on Voltas are different compared to the
tensor cores on Turing and Ampere, and the shared memory layout
required is different.
Each Volta tensor core multiplies 4 matrices of shape 8x4 and 4x4
(i.e. the mma.sync.aligned.m8n8k4 instruction). Each Turing and Ampere
tensor core multiply 1 matrix of shape 16x8 and 8x8, or 16x16 and 16x8
(i.e. the mma.sync.aligned.m16n8k8 and mma.sync.aligned.m16n8k16
instruction). This means that inputs to the mma instructions need to
be laid out differently in shared memory. This shared memory
load/store is the trickiest part.

